# Batch file variable value not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can anybody suggest what is wrong in following code.

```
@echo off

set /a x=1

:while
set /a sta=0

if %x% lss 5 (

    for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('ping 127.0.0.%x%') do (set sta="1"
        if "%%i" == "bytes=32" (echo 111111111
            set /a sta=1
        )
    )


    if %sta% == 1 echo 127.0.0.%x% - ONLINE
    if %sta% == 0 echo 127.0.0.%x% - OFFLINE

    set /a x+=1
    goto while
)

pause
```

It is always going to if condition 'if %sta% == 0'. It is never going to condition if %sta% == 1 .

It seems the sta variable value is not changing.

Comment: Although this may not be considered an answer, I would recommend using Powershell to do this kind of extensive conditions and looping.  There is much better tool support for Powershell (Powershell ISE etc.) and debugging this kind of issue will be a snap.  It does not require much effort to convert this kind of logic in Powershell too.

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: @npocmaka thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @npocmaka for valuable information. Following code works,

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a x=1

:while
set sta=0

if %x% lss 5 (

    for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('ping 127.0.0.%x%') do (
        if "%%i" == "bytes=32" (
            set sta=1
        )
    )

    if !sta! == 1 echo 127.0.0.%x% - ONLINE
    if !sta! == 0 echo 127.0.0.%x% - OFFLINE

    set /a x+=1
    goto while
)

pause
```